# Out of scope function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async.js

I'm trying to write a function that builds an array where each value of the array is a value pulled from an API using a unique url, once the value is fetched from the API it is pushed into the existing array.

Basically when the function is called I want to populate an array with fetched API data for each stock ticker listed in the List

I wrote the below functions to try and solve this but I cant seem to get the function call in the second function in scope to where it works.  I'm getting "'getIntradayPrice' is not defined" when called in the second function. Any ideas how to fix this? Is there a completely different way to do this that I'm missing?

```
const List = [
  { tick: "AAPL", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "GOOG", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "TSLA", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "J", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "AMZN", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "FB", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "BABA", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "JNJ", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "JPM", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "XOM", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
];

async function getIntradayPrice(tick) {
  const resp = await fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`);
  return resp.json();
}

async function totalPortfolio() {
  const respPromises = List.map(({ tick }) => getIntradayPrice(tick));
  const respArrays = await Promise.all(respPromises);
  console.log(respArrays);
}
```

**EDIT

If it helps this code is in between a component declaration and a render() method

```
class TitleCards extends Component {

***Above CODE***

render(){  
        return(
              <div className="positioning"> 
                    {this.totalPortfolio()}
                </div>
....
```

Comment: If those methods are part of a class you need to access them as such, ie `this.getIntradayPrice()`. Also I don't think you can use async functions in the render as they wont have completed by the time it completes

Comment: You should not do that fetching from inside your render function.

Comment: In your first code example I don't see any reason getIntradayPrice wouldn't be available to totalPortfolio. If these are methods on your component class, then as @PatrickEvans says, you'd need to reference it accordingly with `this.getIntradayPrice()`; it doesn't exist in the outer scope.

Comment: That fixed it! Obvious mistake, thanks for the help.